# userauth_pubkey: signature algorithm ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms after upgrade of OpenSSH

Tags: ssh, freebsd, ssh-keys, rsa

After an upgrade I can no longer log in to my box (FreeBSD 14.0) using RSA key getting:

```
userauth_pubkey: signature algorithm ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms
```

in `/var/logs/auth.log`

on every login attempt via SSH using trusted keys that worked perfectly well pre-update.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that with the upgrade of the OS and OpenSSH there is a new setting:

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` :

```
...
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa
```

Adding the accepted algorithm helps after restarting the service. On FreeBSD:

```
sudo service sshd restart
```

Comment: It's not a "new setting". This key type is deprecated and now disabled by default. You reenabled it. But, keep in mind it was disabled for a reason; consider switching to more recent ECC-based algorithms.